# Is a Core Data model diagram view saved?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm having a small issue with my core data model. The layout in the diagram view keeps reverting and all the entities are stacked on top of each other.

Does XCode save the layout information in the .xcdatamodel? If so, is this information added to source control by default or do I have to track other files as well? Or is it saved in user preferences similar to breakpoints and the user interface layout ?

Anyone else having this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in the data model file. There's no separate file to track, it's in the same file as the entity definitions.

However Xcode doesn't always retain this data. It's a bug. I've long since given up on the diagram view, in part because I had to clean it up so often when Xcode lost the arrangement and put all the entities in the center of the diagram.

File a bug, and stop using the diagram view. It's the best way to maintain your sanity.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but for Googlers... Xcode 7 is still quirky with this. As near as I can tell, this info DOES get saved correctly, but only when the model itself is saved. Looks as if Xcode only recognizes the MOM needs saving IFF you make changes to the actual model, not the model's diagram. Personally, my build settings are set to automatically save unsaved files on a build, so I assume everything is up to date when I build. This will not cover MOM diagram changes if the model itself was not changed - in those cases need to manually hit Cmd-S after adjusting the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

you can view separate entity and you can also drag and drop entity for clear view.
there are some button in bottom right use them.

Comment: true, i moved them around. but after coming back to the diagram after some time, they're all stacked again.